# Inserting data using php and mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to take user inputed values from the form and save them in database using php. Here is my `dbConfig` file:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "testDB");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->query("USE testDB");

?>
```

and here is my `Index.php`

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="$1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <title>test</title>

        <?php
        include_once 'dbConfig.php';
        ?>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form> 
        <label id="first"> First name:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
        <label id="first">Password</label><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
        <label id="first">Email</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
        </form>

        <button type="submit" name="save">save</button>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['save'])){
          $query = "INSERT INTO testDB VALUES (username, password, email)";
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:** Im not sure if my way is even correct and the php code in `Index.php` for inserting values doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form>` is equivalent to `<form method="get">` and you're using a POST array for the submit button.

Both need to match, so change it to `<form method="post">`

However this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO testDB VALUES (username, password, email)";
```

String values require them to be quoted.

I.e.: `VALUES ('username', 'password', 'email')`

However, you did not specify the columns, so you need to make sure that the total amount of columns match what you have in your database.

If not, then you need to specify them.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO testDB (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('username', 'password', 'email')
```

Check for errors on your query.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer and I'll keep in mind not to make such a silly mistakes, but it doesn't really solve the problem, database is still empty.

Comment: @2-D You're welcome. I did make a few edits to it, so you'll need to reload it. Also if `$mysqli->query("USE testDB");` fails you, then you'll need to use a direct query for it. I.e.: `$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO testDB VALUES (username, password, email)");`

Comment: @2-D One thing though; you have inputs in your form but not using any of those for your query. You only did `VALUES (username, password, email)` which as I wrote in my answer need to be quoted as shown up there. If the intention is to use the input from the form, then you need to assign POST arrays to variables here. What I posted should have at least entered the words `'username', 'password', 'email'` in the db.

Comment: Thanks, I did a mistake that I found I wrote `INSERT INTO testDB` but the table name is users. I changed Insert query to say users instead of testDB but all these fixes that You suggested still doesn't help

Comment: @2-D drop the `$mysqli->query("USE testDB");` you don't need it. You're already choosing the db in your first line of code. What I posted in my answer and in comments should work. Again; check for errors as I stated in my answer. There isn't really anything else I can add to the answer that hasn't already been said here in comments.

Comment: @2-D Plus, if that's your actual code (it's probably not, but I had to mention it), then you've missed the document declaration in your 2nd file. I.e.: `<!DOCTYPE html>`  to be added before `<head>`.

Comment: this might sound stupid, but I installed `LAMP` on ubuntu and thats what I'm using, do I need to install something else to use `MySQLi` commands? Maybe its just that I dont have something installed. My database is created using terminal and mysql. Yes I just deleted those lines from my post, they are in the code.

Comment: @2-D I'm a * NIX and WAMP guy. I won't be able to help you with that, sorry. All I can think of is that you need a stable PHP environment, with MySQL installed and that you're running as `http://localhost/file.xxx`. I wish I could be of more help here. I've basically answered what I saw and didn't know till now. See if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php yields anything and check your phpinfo.

Comment: *All OK Ralph?* Ding!

Comment: *Yep Sam* @JayBlanchard Ding!